# 3gpp/audio quicktime embed

Tags: audio, embed, quicktime, 3gp

How to embed a 3gpp audio file with quicktime or any other plugin (couldn't find another one) into a website?

this one is not working for me...getting a question mark on the quick time symbol..

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" WIDTH="176"HEIGHT="170" CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
<PARAM name="SRC" VALUE="recording600855144.3gpp">
<PARAM name="AUTOPLAY" VALUE="false">
<param NAME="type" VALUE="audio/quicktime">
<PARAM name="CONTROLLER" VALUE="true">
<EMBED SRC="recording600855144.3gpp" WIDTH="176" HEIGHT="170" AUTOPLAY="false" CONTROLLER="true" type="audio/3gpp" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

I also want controllers play, pause, stop

Answer (score 1):

```
// Code for embedding quicktime player:

<embed width="300" height="18" type="video/quicktime" 
   pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
   src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp"
   controller="true"
   autoplay="false>"
</embed>
```

I found it at the website below and it is working for me:

http://www.iwebformusicians.com/Website-Music-Players/QuickTime-Embed.html

**If you want it to work in every browser**, go the end of the following link/ read entire webpage. You will have to use both `<object>` and `<embed>`.

http://edtech2.boisestate.edu/helveyd/edtech583_multimedia/embedding_multimedia_webpage.html